# Как узнать, сколько используется на данный момент RAM памяти на сервере PHP?

Tags: php, linux

Как узнать через *PHP*, сколько оперативной памяти на данный момент занято на сервере? В качестве ОС использую *Linux*.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.memory-get-usage.php http://php.net/manual/ru/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php

Comment: @Visman Необходимо,сколько на *всем* сервере занято оперативки,а не сколько выделено\занято PHP скрипту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В *Linux* информацию о свободной памяти (да и о памяти вообще) можно получить из `/proc/meminfo`. Например, это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
<?php
    $meminfo_lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('/proc/meminfo'));
    $meminfo = array();
    foreach($meminfo_lines as $line) {
        list($key, $val) = explode(':', $line);
        $meminfo[trim($key)] = trim($val);
    }
    echo 'Free memory: ' . $meminfo['MemFree'] . '. Total memory: ' . $meminfo['MemTotal'] . '.';
?>
```